# Postgresql equivalent of DELETE JOIN when table has composite primary key

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables with a linking table and need to delete a record from the linking table.
I can't see a simple way to do this as my linking table doesn't have its own primary key field (it's a composite primary key of the two fields)

My tables:

```
roles
  id
  role_name

permissions
  id
  permission_name

roles_permissions
  role_id
  permission_id
```

I have a role_name and a permisson_name and want to delete the role_permissions row that matches this.

SQL server can do DELETE JOINS and then you just do a simple where clause across the tables but postgresql doesn't seem to support this.

Closest I can find is

```
DELETE FROM TABLE
WHERE id IN (SELECT ...)
```

This doesn't work for me as I don't have a single primary key field, i.e. both fields need to match the results of the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the IN operator with multiple columns

```
DELETE FROM the_table
WHERE (id_1, id_2) IN (SELECT other_id_1, other_id_2 
                       FROM ...)
```

Comment: That's nice and simple. I did try googling for using IN with multiple columns but didn't find anything so thought that it wasn't supported.

Comment: @Mog0: It's been part of the SQL standard since the beginning I think. It's documented (albeit a bit confusing) in [the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN)

Comment: Thanks. I guess one of those times when I wasn't quite searching for the right terms to find the answer I needed. I actually spent a whole afternoon on this before posting to SO!
TBH I tend not to look at the Postgres manual because I find it difficult to understand unless you already know what it's trying to say.

Comment: @Mog0: no offense, but part of becoming proficient with a technology (Postgres in this case) is getting accustomed with its documentation